# Excel import data from web

Tags: microsoft-excel

While importing data from web page the text formatting is lost, ie any data that seems to be numeric is converted to numeric, which should not.

for example:

web data contains

```
0023181
012318U
032454T
0072106
```

Upon import it get converted to

```
23181
012318U
032454T
72106
```

I want to retain all data as text only. It is a web link, dynamic data, able to get refreshed.  Import to excel table retains the formatting but web link is lost

Comment: You actually used ctrl c and ctrl v from a webpage on a browser to your excel grid?

Comment: If you put an apostrophe `"   '   "` as the first character in the cell, the cell will show the literal input. Edit the cells where the display does not match the input and add an apostrophe as the first character. The quick way would be, with the cell highlighted, press `F2`  `Home`  `'` `Tab/Enter`

Comment: this doesnot work, as the data are in thousand and i have to use vlookup, with after every refresh (data changes & formatting too)

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

In blank sheets in Excel, the format setting is normally `General`, so Excel automatically tries to recognize the format of entered data.

You need to change the formatting of all the cells in the sheet you plan to use to 'Text' - or just change the whole sheet:

1. Click in the corner of the sheet right above `1` and left of `A`. The whole sheet will get selected.
2. Right-click in any cell, choose `Format Cells`, and chose `Text`.
3. now copy/paste your data.

Note: Some websites have a funny behavior where the first Copy/Paste always ends as a long single line. I found that if that happens, you can use CTRL+A/CTRL+C/click (which deselects)/CTRL+A/CTRL-C again, and *then* paste.

Comment: This cannot work as there are numeric values too, on which formulas are applied, moreover i want it refreashed periodically

Comment: You only need to do the formatting once, and can still apply formulas to it (use `VALUE(cell)` where needed). But you said in the question: "I want to retain all data as text only". What is it now? Text only or not text only??

Comment: few column are numeric few text and one (main) is alphanumeric (whose formatting is to be retained), the number of row keeps on increasing after every refresh. I don't want to copy/paste each time rather just refresh like a tracker.

Comment: you can of course selectively set the format too. I just thought that the whole sheet is easier. Select the column headers you want to have treated as text, and change only those.

Comment: Changing format not working.